# NestJS GET function in service & controller return 404 error

Tags: node.js, typescript, postman, nestjs

I'm trying to create simple GET logic, but when try it in Postman receive 404 error.

**books.service.ts** - there is the simple logic:

```
constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Books) private readonly booksRepo: Repository<Books>,
    ) { }

    async getBooks(): Promise<Books[]> {
        const allBooks = await this.booksRepo.find();
        return allBooks;
    }
```

**books.controller.ts** - without any guard

```
SERVER_URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000';

    constructor(private readonly booksService: BooksService) { }

    @Get('books')
    // @UseGuards(AuthGuard());
    async index(): Promise<Books[]> {
        return await this.booksService.getBooks();
    }
```

Books entity is ok, and all books are in data base. The server is up. Can't understand why receive 404 error on /books...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we comment on deleted post you need to delete 'books' from @get(), because you're using 'books' at @Controller(). In the future paste the whole part of yout code, so it can been easy to find this small bugs:

```
@Controller('books')
export class BooksController {
    SERVER_URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000';

    constructor(private readonly booksService: BooksService) { }

    @Get()
    // @UseGuards(AuthGuard());
    async index(): Promise<Books[]> {
        return await this.booksService.getBooks();
    }
}
```